# Define a column name and limit data within the query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO `bindParam()` to be able to define a column name within a query.

This is what I've tried so far

**EDIT**:

```
$item = "Fruits";
$num = "5";
$tot = (int)$num;

$sql = "SELECT categories.item, price.:itm 
            FROM categories 
               LEFT JOIN price 
                   ON categories.iID = price.iID 
                        WHERE price.:itm = :availability 
                            ORDER BY categories.item 
                                ASC LIMIT :lmt";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':itm', $item);
$stmt->bindParam(':lmt', $tot);
$stmt->execute(array(':availability'=>"1"));
$mulu = $statementa->fetchColumn();
```

HOw can I count and limit for 5 results?

Comment: 5 results of what? Also you missed `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: Learn SQL - `ORDER BY %FIELD_NAME% ASC`

Comment: @u_mulder: This is my actual sql. I've updated my post.

Comment: You cannot use field name as a placeholder for a prepared statement. Period.

Comment: @u_mulder but how does it work if I try `WHERE price.{$item}= :availability ` ?

Comment: This `WHERE price.{$item}` is not a placeholder. `price.:itm` is a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind column, only values:

```
$sql = "SELECT categories.item, price.$item 
            FROM categories 
               LEFT JOIN price 
                   ON categories.iID = price.iID 
                        WHERE price.$item = :availability 
                            ORDER BY categories.item 
                                ASC LIMIT :lmt";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
#$stmt->bindParam(':itm', $item);
$stmt->bindParam(':lmt', $tot);
$stmt->execute(array(':availability'=>"1"));
$mulu = $statementa->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Also `SELECT categories.item, price.:itm`

Comment: thanks. HOw do you write if there were two or more to be bind? can this be done as an array? `$stmt->bindParam(array(':lmt'=>$tot, );`

Comment: just add as many as you need `$stmt->bindParam(':lmt1',$tot );` , `$stmt->bindParam(':lmt2',$tot );` etc...

Comment: array thats for execute for example `$stmt->execute(array(':lmt1'=>$tot, ':lmt2'=>$tot));`

Comment: exactly.. that is what was in my mind. I thought an array could be used inside of a `bindParam()`. So`$stmt->bindParam()` should be written for each bind?

Comment: No you cannot do that, i suggest you to  chhose one way but do not mix them

Comment: I use curly braces around the column name variable when it is essential to pass a column name. Is this a safe method? e.g.: `WHERE price.{$item} = :availability `

Comment: Yes thats good or u can use string formatting with sprintf() function